# How to use a Select with OR in PHP - odbc_prepare Issue

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I'm using Microsoft SQL Server for this

```
function novogetListagemClientes($conn, $User){
$stmt = odbc_prepare($conn, 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE id IN ( SELECT idCliente FROM ligacoes WHERE ligacoes.idGest = ? OR idSocioG = ? OR idFunc = ? OR idColab = ? OR idSub = ? )');
$success = odbc_execute($stmt, array($User));
while($myRow = odbc_fetch_array($stmt))
{
    $rows = $myRow;
}
if(empty($rows))
{
    return array();
}
return utf8_converter($rows);
}
```

That's my PHP Function and I want that all the '?' have the same number, how should I fill that array ?
Right now when I use this query in my page it returns nothing, but in Navicat using query builder, returns what I expect.

Error I get: **Warning**: odbc_execute(): SQL error: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Syntax error or access violation, SQL state 37000 in SQLDescribeParameter

If switch the '?' by a number that exists, I get the true value.

**Update**:If I switch the ? by '.$User.' and take of the array part it works

Comment: Pass user five times: `$success = dbc_execute($stmt, array($User, $User, $User, $User, $User));`

Comment: @u_mulder Still not working :\

Comment: Is it `dbc_execute` or `odbc_execute`?

Comment: @u_mulder it's odbc I don't know how it got erased here

Comment: I don't know about the other parts of the code, but I'd write the SQL as `SELECT * FROM users WHERE id IN ( SELECT idCliente FROM ligacoes WHERE ? in (ligacoes.idGest, idSocioG, idFunc, idColab, idSub))` that will also mean you only need to replace one instance of the parameter.

Comment: @SteveLovell I tested on Navicat and that worked perfectly fine, but on my page it doesn't.

`function novogetListagemClientes($conn, $idUser){

 $stmt = odbc_prepare($conn, 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE id IN ( SELECT idCliente FROM ligacoes WHERE ? in (ligacoes.idGest, idSocioG, idFunc, idColab, idSub))');
 $success = odbc_execute($stmt, array($idUser));
 while($myRow = odbc_fetch_array($stmt))
 {
  $rows = $myRow;
 }
 if(empty($rows))
 {
  return array();
 }
 return utf8_converter($rows);
}`

I'm using PHP 5.5 may that interfere?

Comment: What error messages do you get? Also, I believe utf8_converter is not a built-in php function. Have you defined it elsewhere?

Comment: @SteveLovell Yes I've set utf8_converter before , in another function.
**Warning**: odbc_execute(): SQL error: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Syntax error or access violation, SQL state 37000 in SQLDescribeParameter

Comment: The error message suggests either the ODBC connection is having trouble interpreting the SQL (possibly the SQL is invalid, but if it runs in Navicat that shouldn't be the issue), or that the user you are connecting as via the ODBC lacks permissions. I'd be tempted to change the `SELECT *` to pick particular column names. Start with just a single column as a proof of concept. If that doesn't make any difference, then check the ODBC set up (in particular any default database/user settings).

Comment: One way to check the user, would be to use the one from the ODBC connection to establish the connection in Navicat (if you weren't already), and see if the code still runs.

Comment: @SteveLovell In Navicat I've already been using the login that I use in ODBC Connection, and it can pick up just a column one by one.

Update: The query works perfectly on the page, but when I use it on a function with a variable it doesn't work anymore and returns null

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your last comment. Please update your original question to include the latest version of the code, details of any error messages or unwanted behaviour along with the behaviour you're expecting.

Comment: @SteveLovell Edited.

Comment: I reckon the ODBC is struggling with the `prepare`. Here's a different format for the SQL which should return the same results: `SELECT DISTINCT u.* FROM users u
JOIN ligacoes l ON u.id in (l.idGest, l.idSocioG, l.idFunc, l.idColab, l.idSub)
WHERE u.id = ?` . Depending on your data, the `DISTINCT` may not be needed.

Comment: @SteveLovell That query isn't returning what I want, sorry

Comment: You're right. I got confused. Here's a new attempt `SELECT DISTINCT u.* FROM users u JOIN ligacoes l ON u.id = l.idCliente WHERE ? in (l.idGest, l.idSocioG, l.idFunc, l.idColab, l.idSub)`

Comment: @SteveLovell Yup, that query works, thanks ! Everything fine now.
Now my question is another XD That I'm not getting the way to put my SELECT on a normal HTML Table. It's just putting 1 letter each row

Comment: Okay, I'll write my comments into a proper answer (for you to accept, hopefully). If you get stuck with presenting your data in a table, come back to SO with another question.

Comment: @SteveLovell Okay, Okay I'll wait that comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is a summary of interactions in comments on the original question.

Having checked that the ODBC connection was fine (data is returned when the relevant parameter was "hardcoded"), I surmised that the problem was that the ODBC connection wasn't coping with the "Prepare" statement. This will likely have been because the parameters to be passed were not in the outermost `WHERE` clause and so prior to executing the query the connection couldn't work out the overall shape of the resulting data.

To get around this, we refactored the SQL code to remove the subquery and so put the parameter in the outermost `WHERE` clause.

The SQL therefore changed from

```
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE id IN ( SELECT idCliente
              FROM ligacoes
              WHERE ? in (ligacoes.idGest, idSocioG, idFunc, idColab, idSub))
```

to

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.*
FROM users u
     JOIN ligacoes l ON
         u.id = l.idCliente
WHERE ? in (l.idGest, l.idSocioG, l.idFunc, l.idColab, l.idSub)
```

And with that change the code ran without complaint.